# different pip versions for pip and sudo pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, osx-yosemite

I am using OSX Yosemite, and python version 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)

Every time I use `pip`, it returns `You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Typing `pip -V` returns `pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

When I tried to upgrade pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`, I received the following error message

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
     requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Users/YTQ/anaconda/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

I thought this could be a permissions issue, so I used `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`.

However, now when I call `sudo pip -V`, it returns `pip 9.0.1 from /Users/YTQ/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`.

For `pip -V` without `sudo`, it is still pip 8.1.2.

Moreover, when I type `which pip` and `sudo which pip`, both will return `/Users/YTQ/anaconda/bin/pip`

May I know how to address this `pip` upgrading issue? Have I misused the `sudo` command?

Comment: Did you use sudo when you installed Anaconda? Did you export the PATH in your "~/.bash_profile"? Should be export PATH="/Users/YTQ/anaconda/bin:$PATH". Then "source .bash_profile".

Comment: @John Morrison Hi John, I think I installed Anaconda using sudo. When I opened my bash_profile, it shows: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ ` and `# added by Anaconda2 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/YTQ/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`  so it seems the path had been added.

Comment: It is always best to not have the PYTHONPATH set as this is pointing to the system python and not anaconda. Try commenting it out. and launching a new terminal. If pip was installed with sudo it may not have permissions for your user. The easiest solution is to remove anaconda "rm -rf ~/anaconda"  and reinstall not using sudo. The issue is 'sudo' uses its own secure path and not user's path determined by bash environment variable PATH.